# Problemas com Matrizes - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matriz

1 - Ler uma matriz D 5 x 5 (considere que não serão informados valores duplicados). A seguir ler um número X e escreva uma mensagem indicando se o valor de X existe ou NÃO na matriz.

2 - DESAFIO | Consutra uma matriz 10 x 10 com valores randômicos. A matriz não pode ter valores repetidos.

Depois apresente:

a) o resultado da soma de todos os valores da matriz;

b) o resultado da soma dos valores da diagonal principal;

c) o resultado da soma dos valores da diagonal secundária;

d) o resultado da soma da coluna central;

Até o presente momento, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
from random import randint

matriz = []

for linha in range(10):
    linha = []

    for coluna in range(10):
        linha.append(randint(0, 10000))

    matriz.append(linha)

for linha_matriz in matriz:
    print(linha_matriz)
```

Retorno :

```
[710, 4334, 3483, 5554, 93, 3776, 7272, 434, 8028, 7264]
[7909, 4394, 2181, 595, 204, 5274, 9520, 931, 1074, 7914]
[537, 2488, 221, 2982, 2077, 4088, 4948, 7703, 6901, 9055]
[5559, 7666, 7520, 26, 7479, 3188, 3179, 9080, 2998, 1152]
[1319, 565, 3659, 3863, 5273, 4287, 2816, 3573, 7305, 5651]
[8688, 2991, 5008, 2218, 7331, 569, 930, 4206, 1547, 22]
[2180, 7008, 3027, 597, 9550, 440, 6826, 9153, 7700, 2889]
[4929, 5792, 8233, 2604, 3764, 7251, 7469, 9888, 3777, 3286]
[4535, 5478, 4723, 872, 5162, 4547, 1570, 5542, 6809, 6064]
[3936, 2606, 1269, 7249, 1156, 6134, 8334, 5816, 1425, 6467]
```

Como resolver os problemas de das questões: a,b,c e d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A soma total é simples:

```
somaTotal = 0
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        for j in range(len(matriz)):
            somaTotal += matriz[i][j]
    print('somaTotal: ',somaTotal)
print('########################')
```

Para a diagonal principal observe que os índices são iguais, para valores que pertencem a ela

```
#soma diagonal principal
somaDiaPrincipal = 0
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz)):
        if(i == j):
           somaDiaPrincipal += matriz[i][j]
print('somaDiaPrincipal: ',somaDiaPrincipal)
print('########################')
```

A diagonal secundaria tem a soma dos seus índices igual a nove (9)

```
somaDiaSecundaria = 0
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz)):
        if((i+j) == 9):
            somaDiaSecundaria += matriz[i][j]
print('somaDiaSecundaria: ',somaDiaSecundaria)
```

Observe que o valor de j para a mesma coluna é sempre igual, se por exemplo você quer somar a coluna 4 coloque j == 4

```
#soma coluna central
somaColunaCentro = 0
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz)):
        if(j == 4):
            somaColunaCentro += matriz[i][j]
print('somaColunaCentro: ',somaColunaCentro)
```

Comment: Sabe responder a questão 1?

Comment: Percorre toda a matriz e compara cada valor com X, se forem iguais então X esta na matriz

Comment: Está correto, ver se é indentação. Não precisa do if

Comment: Era apenas a posição do código

Comment: o print estava no lugar errado

Comment: @Dark_Lord e Bernardo, para as 2 últimas soluções (diagonal secundária e coluna central), é melhor usar o tamanho da matriz em vez de valores fixos (`i + j == len(matriz) - 1` e `j == (len(matriz) // 2) - 1` por exemplo). E para a soma total, outra alternativa é `sum(sum(linha) for linha in matriz)`

Comment: Isso tornaria o código mais reutilizável para qualquer matriz do formato  (N x N)